# Clang error, no viable conversion

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, wchar-t, char16-t

I am facing an issue with clang 3.1. This particular issue does not arise with GCC 4.2. The following is an example of the error that occurs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

typedef unsigned short char16_t;
typedef char16_t TCHAR;

typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR, std::char_traits<TCHAR>, std::allocator<TCHAR> > wstringT;

template<class T>
inline wstringT MyTestFunction(const T& source)
{
std::wstringstream out;
out << source ;
return out.str();    // error occurs here
};
```

The error message states:

```
No viable conversion from '__string_type' (aka 'basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >') to 'wstringT' (aka 'basic_string<TCHAR, std::char_traits<TCHAR>, std::allocator<TCHAR> >')
```

The code is compiled with the compiler flag -fshort-wchar, which is supposed to convert wchar_t to a 16 bit unsigned short. I am compiling the code on XCode v4.3.2.

Comment: why not use `wchar_t` as `TCHAR`? `wchar_t` may or may not be the same as `unsigned short` aka `char16_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `TCHAR` you have to make every template expand to use it including `wstringstream` you actually want a `basic_stringstream<TCHAR>` or you could:

```
typedef std::basic_stringstream<TCHAR> tstringstream;
```